# Peculiar issue with wiping the underlying buffer of NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a technique outlined in the book **Hacking and Securing iOS Applications** (relevant section [here](https://books.google.gr/books?id=2D50GNA1ULsC&pg=PA265&lpg=PA265&dq=CFStringGetCStringPtr+memset&source=bl&ots=YQNO5yFjvz&sig=YEs-g7-ECvYuwakM-LUJ1Q6rv3g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=S317U5eFApakqAb144CwAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=CFStringGetCStringPtr%20memset&f=false)) to wipe the underlying buffer of a `NSString` as shown below.

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"];
unsigned char *text = (unsigned char*)CFStringGetCStringPtr((CFStringRef)s, CFStringGetSystemEncoding());
if (text != NULL)
{
    memset(text, 0, [s length]);
}
```

This works, unless the string is a certain value.

```
// The following crashes with EXC_ACCESS_ERROR on memset
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No"];
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Yes"];

// These work fine though
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"];
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Do"];
NSString *s = [@"N" stringByAppendingString:@"o"];
```

It looks like certain strings are not created on the heap but is optimized by making it point to a read-only string table even if the string is created on the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed constant string are not created on the heap and are in read-only memory. This includes a few that look like runtime but are made compile-time constants, your examples are such statements.

With this statement fragment there is no reason not to make it a compile-time constant.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No"]
```

it is equivalent to:

```
@"No"
```

Suggestion, file a bug report requesting a secure string class, I have. Several have been filed and I have been told that if there are enough (whatever that amount might be) are files it will implement it.

It is possible to subclass `NSString`, not easy but you will have compete control of the actual buffer and it should not be subject to possible failure due to Apple changing the implementation detail. I have done that successfully.

Comment: Would you happen to know what strings are included in this list?  "No" and "Yes" were the only two I could find.  Yes, I plan on submitting a ticket.

Comment: All `NSString` literals.

Comment: It is an LLVM detail and may change. Possibly it is not possible to cover all possibilities easily (guess). Also, multiple identical string literals are usually coalesced together (there are certain cases where this does not happen). The best bet is to either subclass `NSString` or to ignore the in-memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

`NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No"];` will be optimised to `NSString *s = @"No";` because there are no substitutions in the format. Assigning a literal will give you a pointer to the readonly text segment of the loaded binary.

`NSString *s = [@"N" stringByAppendingString:@"o"];` will create a new string on the heap and return a reference to it.  The heap is read-write even though the datatype `NSString` is readonly.

When you get the CString pointer to the underlying data it's pointing either into read-only data in the first case, or read-write data in the second.  The memset will fail on the readonly memory, but succeed on the read-write.

Comment: Shouldn't [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"] also point to the RO text segment?  However, this does not crash.

Comment: It is an implementation issue in LLVM.

Comment: Converting your call to `stringWithFormat` to a literal is a compiler optimisation. There's no predicting optimisations. Maybe it found other instances of @"Yes" and @"No" which made the optimisation worthwhile, but no other instances of @"Hello".